# Rails executing too much SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've started to notice via Terminal that my Rails app is producing way too many SQL statements, many of which aren't required. I do remember reading somewhere this can be a problem and right now as my data grows it's noticeably slowing the app down.

For example, I have releases that have tracks. Artists can be assigned to both tracks and releases. When I load a release that has only 8 tracks it seems to be running through every single track in the DB to find those relationships!?!

For example, see below and this is a very small sample, but none of these tracks are actually associated to the release. It's going through every track in the DB!!

Any general pointers?

```
Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 12
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 19
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 21
  Artist Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 22
  Artist Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 23
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 24
  Artist Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 25
  Artist Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 26
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 27
  Artist Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 28
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 29
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 30
  Artist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artists_tracks` ON `artists`.`id` = `artists_tracks`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists_tracks`.`track_id` = 31
```

Here's the models involved:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :releases, :through => :artist_releases 
  has_many :artists_tracks
  has_many :tracks, :through => :artists_tracks
end

class ArtistRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :release
end

class ArtistsTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_releases
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist_releases    
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks, :order => "releases_tracks.position"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases_tracks    
end

class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'releases_tracks.position ASC'
  acts_as_list :scope => :release_id
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :releases, :through => :releases_tracks
  has_many :artists_tracks
  has_many :artists, :through => :artists_tracks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists_tracks
end
```

Comment: Might want to include the basics of your relationships (model definitions).

Comment: Make sure you don't loop over a query.  all those queries should be turned into one with an IN statement

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'll try and add in a sec, it's all quite involved so i'll have to strip back a few things for clarity.

Comment: @Limey - Thanks, i'll check out IN statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the queries Rails is generating, it looks like you're doing something like this, which loads each artist individually when you refer to it:

```
release.tracks.each{ |t| t.artist }
```

You should be eagerly loading the artists so that they are pre-loaded in a single query:

```
release.tracks.includes(:artist).each{ |t| t.artist }
```

The `includes` method is very flexible, and allows you to eagerly load multiple associations, or even nested associations:

```
Release.first.includes(:releases_tracks => {:track => :artist})
```

This will load the first Release, then all of its ReleaseTracks, and then all of their Tracks, and the all of the Tracks' Artists in just 4 queries (1 per table). This is much more efficient than loading each record individually.

There's more information in the section on [Eager Loading Associations in the Active Record Query interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: Ahhh! `release.tracks.each{ |t| t.artist }` looks very familiar so i'll see if I can refactor as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite the same actually, in my view the tracklisting is pulled in with `<% @release.releases_tracks.sort_by { |releases_tracks| releases_tracks.position }.each  do |releases_track| %>` and then artists with `<%= releases_track.track.artists.map { |a| a.name }.join (",") %>`. Should I be doing something elsewhere?

Comment: I suspect you want to use `includes` when you initially load `@release`, something like: `@release = Release.foo.includes(:releases_tracks => {:track => :artists})` but if you update your question with more information about your models (and the code you posted in your comments) I, or someone else, will be able to give a better answer.

Comment: I've added the models involved above now.

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on the models.

Comment: Incidentally, depending on what fields your models have you might be able to refactor a little and reduce complexity by using `has_and_belongs_to_many` in some places, and/or getting rid of the `ArtistRelease` model and using `has_many :releases, :through => :artist_tracks` instead.

Comment: This seems to work nicely. I figured out that there was also a load of SQL produced that needn't have been.....some occasionally loaded pop ups, that i'm now going to load via AJAX when needed.